# Angular ControlValueAccessor onChanges not updating form control value

Tags: angular, forms, onchange

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of the component/problem reproduced.

I've built a custom input component that:

1. takes an array of user objects for typeahead filtering
2. displays your selections as tags
3. form control value is an array of the selected users `users[]`

The issue is that [adding a result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-tags%2Finput-tags.component.ts) (input-tags.component) does not update the form (app.component) and I can't understand why.

**input-tags.component.ts**

```
addTag(contact: any) {
   ...
   this.onChange(this.tags); // update controller value
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.form.controls['users'].valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  this.control = data; // always null
});
```

`onChanges` is called as expected and everything works fine except the form control is always null. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in your `addTag()` function. You're trying to access a parameter that doesn't exist in your `typeaheadSource`. Change the `contact.userId` to `contact.id` and you should be good to go.